# What else ROS can do?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I have learn all tutorial about ros like rqt graph, rosnode list making package and the others. I also have learnt  all tutorial about turtlebot like gmapping,rvis, teleop, and other things. I just want to know other than that, what else ROS can do, or what else are interesting about ROS that can impress other people?

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200317/what-else-ros-can-do?/) by [ghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21020/ghost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many ways to develop your ROS project and impress other people. I can propose something such as:

- Implement on real robot
- Build your robots and your working environment with some simulator (gazebo)
- Try image processing with opencv
  ..........
  when you develop your own project, you will find other interesting thing ^^

---

Originally posted by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) with karma: 60 on 2015-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0